# function boost::filesystem::complete being reported as possible memory leak by valgrind

Tags: c++, boost

I have code that looks like

```
void Image::Init(std::string _filename)
{
  boost::filesystem::path filepath(_filename);
  boost::filesystem::path realpath = boost::filesystem::complete(filepath);  //leak point
  ...
}
```

For some reason, valgrind is reporting that the line with the comment above is leaking.
It's one of those "possibly lost" reports. 
Nonetheless I wanted to figure out why it might be possibly lost.
I am using boost version 1.38. Valgrind 3.7. My OS is linux 2.6.29

The valgrind output looks like such:

```
==32009== 471 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 161 of 174
==32009==    at 0x40220EE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:263)
==32009==    by 0x84DAC61: operator new(unsigned int) (ZeroNew.cpp:11)
==32009==    by 0x44C79DA: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==32009==    by 0x44C8947: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==32009==    by 0x44CA3A7: std::string::reserve(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==32009==    by 0x44CA9E3: std::string::operator+=(char) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==32009==    by 0x829189A: boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::string, boost::filesystem::path_traits>::m_append(char) (path.hpp:1079)
==32009==    by 0x829193C: boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::string, boost::filesystem::path_traits>::operator/=(char const*) (path.hpp:1099)
==32009==    by 0x8291977: boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::string, boost::filesystem::path_traits>::operator/=(boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::string, boost::filesystem::path_traits> const&) (path.hpp:203)
==32009==    by 0x8296F24: boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::string, boost::filesystem::path_traits> boost::filesystem::operator/<std::string, boost::filesystem::path_traits>(boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::string, boost::filesystem::path_traits> const&, boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::string, boost::filesystem::path_traits> const&) (path.hpp:521)
==32009==    by 0x829AB20: boost::enable_if<boost::filesystem::is_basic_path<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::string, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >, boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::string, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >::type boost::filesystem::complete<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::string, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >(boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::string, boost::filesystem::path_traits> const&, boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::string, boost::filesystem::path_traits> const&) (operations.hpp:586)
==32009==    by 0x829C41E: boost::filesystem::complete(boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::string, boost::filesystem::path_traits> const&) (operations.hpp:752)
==32009==    by 0x849AF2D: Image::Init(std::string, int) (Image.cpp:50)
```

I am curious if anyone knows why this is happening or if there just is a bug in this code in version 1.38 of boost. If a work around using slightly different syntax is possible, that'd be fantastic.

Thanks.

Comment: For what it is worth - have you tried using a more recent version of boost? 1.38 is pretty outdated, 1.49 is the latest version. Especially boost::filesystem has been completely rewritten from 1.44 on. The routine `boost::filesystem::complete` has been superseded by `boost::filesystem::absolute`. I've testes your code snippet with boost 1.49 and using `absolute` and I don't get any possible leaks.

Comment: I would suggest you download the boost source code, compile it with the libraries you need (that would be at least system and filesystem in your case) and install it somewhere in your home directory (e.g. ~/usr) so that you can test whether the problem also disappears for you..

Comment: Oh, believe me when I say I'd very much like to move up to boost 1.49, but unfortunately I am restricted in this regard (for reasons I think are silly but unfortunately immovable at this point in time). I have no doubt that problem would go away as you say if I were to use 1.49, but that doesn't change what I'm forced to build and deploy with. Yah, it sucks, but I'm hoping that there may be some other syntactic workaround that I may be able to use that'll make it work cleanly.

Comment: Starting to think this might be related to valgrind not liking STL allocators or something, as I see the same thing from time to time when doing stream operations to std out on boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time(); I tried the GLIBXX_FORCE_NEW environment variable, but that didn't do squat. May very well be a valgrind specific false positive.